# Hyperlink a value in SQL Server query result in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008

I am trying to create something for our QA people, where a query that they would run will return a column with hyperlinked values.  I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and SSMS.

**How will I hyperlink results in SSMS so a linked value opens in a browser?**

The idea is that the Qa person can simply click on the link and the appropriate ASP.Net app would open in a browser window.

The query is as below, which is right now showing an unlinked string under DocLink column.

```
SELECT
 DocNumber,
'https://www.xyz.com/mypage.aspx?docNumber=' + CAST(DocNumber AS varchar(20)) AS   
     DocLink
FROM Docs
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way that I found to open URL directly from result pan but following is the way if you want to achieve open hyperlink from within `SSMS`.

**Step 1.**
Cast the result to XML. i.e.

```
SELECT CAST('http://www.google.com' AS XML) Google
```

**Step 2.** 
After executing the query, in the result window, click on the hyperlink. That will open another tab in SSMS.

[image]

[image]

**Step 3.**
In this new tab, right click on the link and select Open URL option. This will open the link into the default browser.

[image]

Try that.

Comment: This is the only solution I found.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the result string as XML:

```
SELECT
CAST('https://www.xyz.com/mypage.aspx?docNumber=100' AS XML)
```

Comment: ErikEJ - That links it, but it doesn't open it in a browser when clicked. Instead it just opens in a SSM tab. Thanks.