# I need to Display Sql Server Query Returned URL Link as Active

Tags: sql-server-2008

Here's my SQL Query - I need the URL Link to display as Active:

```
SELECT     Co,  Aprv,  ApvDate, 'http://URL&id=' 
            + CONVERT(varchar(12), RID, 101) AS URL

FROM       Inv 

WHERE     (Status IN (2, 4, 7)) AND (Amount >= 50000.00) AND 
      (ApvDate >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
    AND ApvDate < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETDATE()),0))

ORDER BY ApvDate
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave more details about the Inv table and its columns, as well as an example on what you are expecting to receive.

Comment: What do you mean by "active"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hyperlink a value in SQL Server query result in SSMS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18832132/73226)